# Using custom container registy in azure ml api v2

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a working azure container registry.  I am able to do git pull, push, etc. using service principal authentication.

However, when I send it to a compute cluster, there is no way that the cluster could pull the correct docker images from the container registry.

Here is output from the cluster run's output:

```
2023/09/25 14:39:53 Downloading source code...
2023/09/25 14:39:54 Finished downloading source code
2023/09/25 14:39:54 Creating Docker network: acb_default_network, driver: 'bridge'
2023/09/25 14:39:55 Successfully set up Docker network: acb_default_network
2023/09/25 14:39:55 Setting up Docker configuration...
2023/09/25 14:39:55 Successfully set up Docker configuration
2023/09/25 14:39:55 Logging in to registry: caf220d1b3fa459e8a75611cec79dbe5.azurecr.io
2023/09/25 14:39:56 Successfully logged into caf220d1b3fa459e8a75611cec79dbe5.azurecr.io
2023/09/25 14:39:56 Volume source scriptsFromEms successfully created
2023/09/25 14:39:56 Executing step ID: acb_step_0. Timeout(sec): 5400, Working directory: '', Network: 'acb_default_network'
2023/09/25 14:39:56 Scanning for dependencies...
2023/09/25 14:39:57 Successfully scanned dependencies
2023/09/25 14:39:57 Launching container with name: acb_step_0
Sending build context to Docker daemon  77.31kB

Step 1/21 : FROM tampere.azurecr.io/custom/ubuntu20.04@sha256:aa19088a50e382bbde8b89e9a5848ef3632736a35dd45d991cae9afa76ed5cba
Get "https://tampere.azurecr.io/v2/custom/ubuntu20.04/manifests/sha256:aa19088a50e382bbde8b89e9a5848ef3632736a35dd45d991cae9afa76ed5cba": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
2023/09/25 14:39:58 Container failed during run: acb_step_0. No retries remaining.
failed to run step ID: acb_step_0: exit status 1

Run ID: cbt failed after 15s. Error: failed during run, err: exit status 1
```

I am using azure ml API v2, like this:

```
from azure.ai.ml import command
...
job = command(
    code="./",
    command=cli_command,
    environment=f"mlflow-env:4",  # *must* provide a version
    compute=cluster_name,
    experiment_name=experiment_name,
    display_name=job_name,
    environment_variables={
        "PYTHONUNBUFFERED":"1"
    }
)
print("LAUNCHING JOB")
ml_client.create_or_update(job)
print("JOB LAUNCHED! - HAVE A NICE DAY")
```

But haven't found any way to add the docker username and password (from the service principal) to the input of the builder function "command".

It seems that in the old v1 API this can be done: [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-train-with-custom-image?view=azureml-api-1&viewFallbackFrom=azureml-api-2)

Is the conclusion then that API v2 is broken or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image build that materializes your AzureML specification happens on an agent ACR provides to run a task. You can authorize AzureML to pass credentials to ACR Task -> docker for private registries. The best way to do so is AzureML Workspace Connections. You specify registry (target), connection type (ACR/ContainerRegistry), AuthType (Basic would work in all the cases, but I'd recommend to generate pull only scoped token), and the actual secret. Once it is set all image builds in the workspace will be authorized to pull base images/artifacts from the registry.

Here are some samples for v2 cli/sdk:

https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/resources/connections/connections.ipynb

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/connection?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: This used to work but now it's broken _again_:

"Unable to get image details.  The auth type ServicePrincipal for base image registry connections is not supported. Please use basic auth (username/password) or registry identity..."

Comment: Well.. I'm going back to the good'ol'- apt get packages at cluster run start.  Poor Ubuntu package servers..

Answer (score 1):

By adjusting [this tutorial for Azure container registry (ACR)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-identity-based-service-authentication?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python#build-azure-machine-learning-managed-environment-into-base-image-from-private-acr-for-training-or-inference) and this [example notebook](https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/resources/connections/connections.ipynb) using Azure Python SDK, I complete the connection of AML workspace with a private container registry with some trial and error.

```yaml
name: test_ws_conn_cr
type: container_registry
target: <url_container_registry>
credentials:
  type: username_password
  username: __TOKEN__
  password: ***
```

Together with

```
az ml connection create --file <yml file> --resource-group <resource group> --workspace-name <workspace>
```

You can check the connection with [`az ml connection show test_ws_conn_cr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/connection?view=azure-cli-latest).

In addition, there seems to be other supported types of credentials such as `pat`, `sas`, `username_password`, `managed_identity`, `service_principal`, `access_key`, and `api_key` as indicated by some error messages if you don't give a correct one. The corresponding configurations for them can be inferred from the respective Azure python SDK docs for [`azure.ai.ml.entities`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-ai-ml/azure.ai.ml.entities?view=azure-python).

Then we can have `FROM <url_container_registry>/image_name:image_tag` in the `DOCKERFILE` we want to use to [create an environment from a Docker build context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-environments-v2?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python#create-an-environment-from-a-docker-build-context).

Answer (score -1):

It seems Azure ML SDK v2 does not currently support passing in the Docker credentials to the `command()` builder function.

However, as per documentation one possible workaround can be by
`Using a managed identity` .

If you are using a managed identity to authenticate with Azure ML, you can use the managed identity to pull Docker images from Azure Container Registry and use the environment in your `command` job.

For details on setup you can check :
[Build Azure Machine Learning managed environment into base image from private ACR for training or inference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-identity-based-service-authentication?view=azureml-api-2&tabs=python#build-azure-machine-learning-managed-environment-into-base-image-from-private-acr-for-training-or-inference)